# Accessing a file from within the class located inside the JAR library

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jar

I have my own JAR library which is in the classpath of my Java EE 5 WebApp. A class in that JAR needs an access to a file in WebApp Resources.

The Question is:

How can I access a file inside a WebApp from a JAR library in the classpath of the WebApp?

Comment: What is "WebApp Resources"? Which path?

Comment: @Marcel Stör file is located in WEB-INF folder

Comment: What kind of class is it? Is it a Servlet or ServletFilter or more generally speaking does it have access to a ServletContext or a Request?

Comment: I would make a ServletContextListener in your library to get access to the files. It is the most safe way. Alternatively the main application code can set a path to resources in global system property so all libraries will get access.

Answer (score 0):

[ServletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/my.txt")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) gives a File.